# Duda "Ver código fuente de la página" en navegadores

Tags: android, html

Primeramente perdón por mi ignorancia. No tengo conocimientos de programación web.

Estoy tratando de tener acceso a nombres e imágenes de la lista de [esta](https://www.forbes.com/celebrities/list/) página mediante el código fuente.

Si inspecciono el código fuente de la página no me parecen ni los nombres ni ningún <*img src*=" con el link de la imagen.

Pero desde inspeccionar elementos, sí me aparece nombres y links de las fotos en el código html.

No entiendo porqué no aparecen cuando inspecciono el código html de la página.

Digamos que lo que quiero es todo el código html de la página para convertirlo a un string y luego poder buscar en él nombres y links de imágenes. Es para un curso de Android.

Gracias de antemano. Se que probablemente sea una pregunta muy tonta, pero si alguien me puede aclarar esto se lo agradecería muchísimo.

[image: Inspeccionar elementos]

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en esa pagina cargan las imagenes mediante una funcion de js, tocaria analizarla con detenimiento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La mayoría de las páginas web modernas están construidas en tu propio navegador al ejecutarse el javascript que contienen. Son páginas "dinámicas".

Si inspeccionas el fuente lo que ves es lo que realmente recibió en navegador, algo de HTML, enlaces a hojas de estilo CSS, y enlaces a codigo javascript. El navegador descarga todo eso y después ejecuta el javascript. Éste, mediante funciones que manipulan el llamado DOM (que es una estructura de datos que contiene de alguna forma los elementos HTML que componen la página), puede crear elementos adicionales, modificar los que había, mostrar unos y ocultar otros, etc.

Lo que ves con "inspeccionar elemento" es el DOM resultante de esas manipulaciones. Ese DOM aún es dinámico, es decir, cambiante, pues el javascript aún se está ejecutando en respuesta a acciones del usuario.

Esto hace muy complejo la extracción de información (*scraping*) del HTML. En general, la única forma fiable de hacerlo es dejar que un navegador real se descargue la página y ejecute el javascript correspondiente y después "manejar por control remoto" (por así decir) ese navegador para que te reporte el DOM resultante, o simular acciones del usuario. Esto puede hacerse desde sistemas de escritorio con bibliotecas como Selenium, pero no creo que haya un equivalente para Android.

Te diría que si es para experimentar y hacer pruebas, busques una página más simple, con contenidos estáticos en vez de dinámicos. Por ejemplo Wikipedia.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Este es el tipo de respuesta que buscaba, todo muy bien explicado y en profundidad. Ya me ha quedado todo claro y entendido. Gracias de corazón.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te dijo Sergio, necesitas un navegador para poder cargar todo el contenido de la pagina.
El metodo que voy a mostrarte quiza no sea el mejor, pero puede ayudarte si lo que quieres es practicar.

- Puedes usar un webview sin layout en Android, cargar la pagina en él y obtener el documento html (completo) a traves de javascript y luego, si quieres, puedes usar la librería [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download) para manipular los elementos html en Android de forma nativa y sencilla.
- Si no quieres usar la libreria [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download) puedes manipular el html directamente con javascript (solo si sabes DOM).
- A continuación te pongo un ejemplo de como obtener el titulo de una pagina, usando [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download) y también usando javascript (DOM).

Ejemplo: Clase MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private String url;
 private WebView webView;
 private Context ctx;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  url = "https://www.forbes.com/celebrities/list/";
  ctx = MainActivity.this;
  cargarWeb();
 }


 private void cargarWeb() {
  webView = new WebView(ctx);
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
  WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
  settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
  settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
  settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
  settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
  settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl(url);
 }
 private void manipularHTML(final WebView view) {

  // javascript para obtener solo un elemento (en ese caso el titulo de la pagina) recuerda que podría haber sido cualquier elemento.
  view.evaluateJavascript("(function(){ return (document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML); })();", new ValueCallback < String > () {
   @Override
   public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
    // value ==> valor obtenido del javascript (titulo de la pagina)

    //obtener titulo
    String tiulo = value;
   }
  });

  // javascript para obtener documento html completo para usar jsoup
  view.evaluateJavascript("(function(){ return (document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML); })();", new ValueCallback < String > () {
   @Override
   public void onReceiveValue(String value) {

    // value ==> valor obtenido del javascript (documento html completo)

    //Ahora puedes manipularlo con la librería jsoup, en ese caso voy a obtener solo el titulo (podría haber sido cualquier elemento)
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html>" + value + "</html>");

    //obtener titulo
    String tiulo = doc.title();

   }
  });
 }
 class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   manipularHTML(view);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Waooh. Esto es lo que andaba buscando, has dado en el clavo. Muchísimas gracias de corazón. Todo super bien explicado y comprensible. Gracias @Iscofield

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ObtenerTextoPagina()
    ' Referencia a Microsoft XML, v6.0 (o la versión más reciente)
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    ' URL de la página web
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://hscomercial.mx/categoria-producto/reposteria/"

    ' Enviar solicitud GET a la URL
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlhttp.send ""

    ' Verificar si la solicitud fue exitosa (código de respuesta 200)
    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        ' Crear un objeto FileSystem para escribir en un archivo de texto
        Dim fs As Object
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        ' Ruta del archivo de texto
        Dim filePath As String
        filePath = "C:\ruben\output.txt"

        ' Crear o sobrescribir el archivo de texto
        Dim file As Object
        Set file = fs.CreateTextFile(filePath, True)

        ' Escribir el contenido de la página en el archivo
        file.WriteLine xmlhttp.responseText

        ' Cerrar el archivo
        file.Close

        MsgBox "El texto de la página se ha guardado correctamente en " & filePath
    Else
        MsgBox "Error al obtener la información de la página. Código de respuesta: " & xmlhttp.Status
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta, que de hecho es más bien una pregunta teórica?